# fmt.Println vs os.Stdout.Write

Tags: go

I had this code where I convert a string into a `[]byte` slice using `json.Marshal`. When printing, why does `fmt.Println()` write numbers to stdout while `os.Stdout.Write` writes the string.

My question is how does `fmt.Println` parse the `[]byte`.

```
package main

import (
        "encoding/json"
        "fmt"
        "os"
    )

func main(){
    str := "My string"
    dat,_:= json.Marshal(str)
    fmt.Println(dat)
    os.Stdout.Write(dat)
}
```

I get the following Output

```
[34 77 121 32 115 116 114 105 110 103 34]
"My string"
```

Comment: It doesn't seem like json plays any relevant part in your problem. Rather it seems you are wondering what `fmt.Println` writes when it's give a `[]byte` argument and why it's different from `os.Stdout.Write`. Did you look at the documentation for `fmt.Println`? I guess it's a bit confusing and needs a bit of searching on that page, but it says that `fmt.Println` uses default formats for its arguments, and the same page says what the default format is for a slice.

Comment: yeah your are right. I used json.Marshal to get the byte array and my question is how fmt.Println parses the ```[]byte```

Comment: Note that `os.Stdout.Write(dat)` does not just print the string, it prints double-quoted string. Ref. https://play.golang.org/p/PeyrXeCKzMz

Comment: @maxim_ge: That's a result of json marshalling, not something done by `os.Stdout.Write`.

Comment: @Marc I do not claim whose result it is. The point is that Output does not correspond to code - last line should be double-quoted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`fmt.Println` generates the friendly format for a byte slice. Because byte slices can contain anything at all (and not just printable characters), it shows you the individual byte values. Per the [docs](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/): a byte slice is printed out as:

> the uninterpreted bytes of the string or slice

On the other hand, `os.Stdout.Write` writes the byte slice to standard out. Because they are printable characters, your terminal renders them properly.

Try it with non-printable characters, and the reason for `fmt.Println`'s behavior will become clear:

```golang
func main() {
    dat := []byte{0, 1, 2, 3, 4}
    fmt.Println(dat)
    os.Stdout.Write(dat)
}
```

Outputs:

```
[0 1 2 3 4]
XXXX // four non-printable character placeholders (based on your terminal)
```

As for json, its output is a byte slice since this is the most useful format to be passed to a writer (network, disk, storage, etc...).